# Utilities.formatDate is changing date format in my spreadsheet when saved as a CSV - Google Sheets / Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The date format is being changed when I save this file as a csv. below picture is what date looks like BEFORE being saved

[image: Date In Spreadsheet BEFORE being saved as a CSV]

Date format AFTER file saved as a CSV

[image]

Below code is what I am using. I have tried to play around with the utitilies but cant get it to change date format in saved csv

```
 function STCSV() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
 //var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('D2D MACRO'), true);

 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy ");

// append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
fileName = formattedDate + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " ST_CSV_IMPORT "  + 
".csv";

Appreciate any help
```

Comment: The Sheets interface automatically formats the dates of the cells unless you indicate otherwise. Where are you using `fileName`? A log of this variable shows the format is correct.

Comment: About `save this file as a csv`, can I ask you about the method of it?